# Why is it giving me an list out of range error?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I had an idea to make a dbms solely using core python,numpy and pandas. My plan was to take 4 attributes as data(Name,age,salary,position) per employee add them to a list and then change that list into dataframe. But i am running into the problem of setting the number of employees and how many times it should ask for inputs and then it should add those to list for an employee and repeat the same by creating a new list but i am running into some probkems please help!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
header_count = int(input("Number of employees: "))
headers = [[] for i in range(1, header_count)]

name= input("Enter the name of the employee: ")
age= int(input("Enter the age of the employee: "))
position= input("Enter the position of the employee: ")
salary= int(input("Enter the salary of the employee: "))

for i in range(1, header_count):
    headers[i].append(name)
    headers[i].append(age)
    headers[i].append(position)
    headers[i].append(salary)
```

note: my skill level is near to a beginner so please pardon my incompetence

Comment: What line raises that error?

Comment: Please post the full error trace.

Comment: Python list indices are 0-based.

Comment: Because you insist on indexing your lists from 1 to n-1, instead of 0 to n-1

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you have is that you are using range(1, N). It iterates from 1 to N-1 so you should use range(N) (eq. to range(0, N), recommended) or range(1, N+1).
Beware accessing to the attributes too, since name is in the position 0 and salary is in the position 3.